# Spring boot + JPA + Sybase "Table not found"

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, sybase

**Issue Resolved**: Below is the issue description and its resolution.

**Issue Description**

Have created Spring boot (v1.4.1 RELEASE) project with SOAP service(SOAP service can be avoided to solve this issue) and Spring data JPA CrudRepository to perform  CRUD operation. Every thing works fine with MYSQL but when i tried to connect it using Sybase, am getting Table not found.
Please help as this is a showstopper for us.

Please help to resolve this issue.

**application.properties**

```
server.port=10000
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.databasePlatform=org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseDialect


# SQL dialect for generating optimized queries
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.database=SYBASE
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

# hikariCP

spring.datasource.dataSourceClassName=com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDataSource
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.connectionTestQuery=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.username=dev
spring.datasource.password=developer
spring.datasource.databaseName=MTW
spring.datasource.serverName=localhost
spring.datasource.portNumber=5000
```

**Entity bean**

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "wallettest")
public class wallet {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "orderId")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "orderInternalId")
    private int orderInternalId;

    @Column(name = "orderStatus")
    private int orderStatus;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getOrderInternalId() {
        return orderInternalId;
    }

    public void setOrderInternalId(int orderInternalId) {
        this.orderInternalId = orderInternalId;
    }

    public int getOrderStatus() {
        return orderStatus;
    }

    public void setOrderStatus(int orderStatus) {
        this.orderStatus = orderStatus;
    }

}
```

**WalletRespository**

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
@Component
@Transactional
// Logically No need @Transactional if there is only one table involved
public interface WalletRepository extends CrudRepository<wallet, Long> {
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "UPDATE wallet SET orderStatus = :orderStatus WHERE id = :orderId AND orderInternalId= :orderInternalId")
    public int updateWalletStatus(@Param("orderId") long orderId, @Param("orderInternalId") int orderInternalId,
            @Param("orderStatus") int orderStatus);
}
```

When SOAP request is being sent, have implemented an Endpoint class which delegated the request with the proper inputs to business layer class, below is the class in business layer which gets invoked, nothing wrong in this class, provided here for reference purpose:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component("WalletUpdatorServiceImpl")
public class WalletUpdatorServiceImpl implements WalletUpdatorService {

    private WalletRepository walletRepository;

    private WalletItemTransformer walletItemTransformer;

    private ExtendedLogger logger = ExtendedLogger.create(WalletUpdatorServiceImpl.class);

    List<OrderUpdateItem> walletUpdateItemsSucceded = null;
    List<OrderUpdateItem> walletUpdateItemsFailed = null;

    @Autowired
    public WalletUpdatorServiceImpl(WalletRepository walletRepository, WalletItemTransformer walletItemTransformer) {
        this.walletRepository = walletRepository;
        this.walletItemTransformer = walletItemTransformer;
    }

    @Override
    public List<OrderUpdateItem> updateWalletStatus(List<OrderUpdateItem> orderUpdateItems) {
        walletUpdateItemsSucceded = new ArrayList<OrderUpdateItem>();
        walletUpdateItemsFailed = new ArrayList<OrderUpdateItem>();

        for (OrderUpdateItem orderUpdateItem : orderUpdateItems) {
            wallet wallet = walletItemTransformer.transformToOrder(orderUpdateItem);

            System.out.println("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^");
            System.out.println("wallet id:" + wallet.getId());
            System.out.println("wallet id:" + wallet.getOrderInternalId());
            System.out.println("wallet status:" + wallet.getOrderStatus());
            System.out.println("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^");

            int count = walletRepository.updateWalletStatus(wallet.getId(), wallet.getOrderInternalId(),
                    wallet.getOrderStatus());

            if (count == 1) {
                logger.audit("%%%%%%%%%%%% SUCCESS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");
                logger.audit(wallet);
                logger.audit("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");
                walletUpdateItemsSucceded.add(orderUpdateItem);
            } else {
                logger.audit("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ FAILED  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@2");
                logger.audit(wallet);
                logger.audit("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@2");
                walletUpdateItemsFailed.add(orderUpdateItem);
            }

        }

        return walletUpdateItemsSucceded;

    }

    public WalletRepository getWalletRepository() {
        return walletRepository;
    }

    public void setWalletRepository(WalletRepository walletRepository) {
        this.walletRepository = walletRepository;
    }

    public WalletItemTransformer getWalletItemTransformer() {
        return walletItemTransformer;
    }

    public void setWalletItemTransformer(WalletItemTransformer walletItemTransformer) {
        this.walletItemTransformer = walletItemTransformer;
    }

    public ExtendedLogger getLogger() {
        return logger;
    }

    public void setLogger(ExtendedLogger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

}
```

Here i want to update the order status based on orderId and orderInternalId.
So instead of using findOne to get the wallettest object from JPA, updating the status property and then doing save object, have directly used @Query annotation to update the required column.

This is working in MYSQL, but with Sybase it is giving error saying "Table not found", the query printed by Hibernate is correct as shown in logs below.

Also when i put spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=**update** in application.propeties, it complains before the hitting the soap service, when the project is executed using mvn spring-boot:run and the hibernate validator is ran, below am attaching both the logs:

**Console log Before setting spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update**

```
    2016-10-07 20:57:28 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  FilterRegistrationBean:258 - Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-10-07 20:57:28 [main] INFO  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:349 - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-10-07 20:57:28 [main] INFO  LogHelper:31 - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: default
        ...]
2016-10-07 20:57:28 [main] INFO  Version:37 - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.11.Final}
2016-10-07 20:57:28 [main] INFO  Environment:213 - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-10-07 20:57:28 [main] INFO  Environment:317 - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-10-07 20:57:28 [main] INFO  Version:66 - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2016-10-07 20:57:29 [main] INFO  HikariDataSource:93 - HikariPool-1 - Started.
2016-10-07 20:57:29 [main] INFO  Dialect:156 - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseDialect
2016-10-07 20:57:29 [main] INFO  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:382 - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-10-07 20:57:30 [main] INFO  QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator:47 - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-10-07 20:57:30 [main] INFO  OrderUpdateEndpoint:25 - Endpoint loaded
2016-10-07 20:57:31 [main] INFO  RequestMappingHandlerAdapter:534 - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@519753fd: startup date [Fri Oct 07 20:57:24
 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-10-07 20:57:31 [main] INFO  RequestMappingHandlerMapping:543 - Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.
web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-10-07 20:57:31 [main] INFO  RequestMappingHandlerMapping:543 - Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.
errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-10-07 20:57:31 [main] INFO  SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:354 - Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-10-07 20:57:31 [main] INFO  SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:354 - Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-10-07 20:57:31 [main] INFO  SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:354 - Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-10-07 20:57:31 [main] INFO  AnnotationMBeanExporter:431 - Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-10-07 20:57:31 [main] INFO  AnnotationMBeanExporter:912 - Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2016-10-07 20:57:31 [main] INFO  AnnotationMBeanExporter:667 - Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
2016-10-07 20:57:31 [main] INFO  Http11NioProtocol:179 - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-10000"]
2016-10-07 20:57:31 [main] INFO  Http11NioProtocol:179 - Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-10000]
2016-10-07 20:57:31 [main] INFO  NioSelectorPool:179 - Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2016-10-07 20:57:31 [main] INFO  TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer:185 - Tomcat started on port(s): 10000 (http)
2016-10-07 20:57:31 [main] INFO  Application:57 - Started Application in 7.788 seconds (JVM running for 12.563)
2016-10-07 20:57:40 [http-nio-10000-exec-1] INFO  [/]:179 - Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'messageDispatcherServlet'
2016-10-07 20:57:40 [http-nio-10000-exec-1] INFO  MessageDispatcherServlet:489 - FrameworkServlet 'messageDispatcherServlet': initialization started
2016-10-07 20:57:40 [http-nio-10000-exec-1] INFO  SaajSoapMessageFactory:139 - Creating SAAJ 1.3 MessageFactory with SOAP 1.1 Protocol
2016-10-07 20:57:40 [http-nio-10000-exec-1] INFO  MessageDispatcherServlet:508 - FrameworkServlet 'messageDispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 40 ms
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
wallet id:1
wallet id:102
wallet status:9
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Hibernate: update wallettest set orderStatus=? where orderId=? and orderInternalId=?
2016-10-07 20:57:40 [http-nio-10000-exec-1] WARN  SqlExceptionHelper:127 - SQL Error: 42102, SQLState: 42S02
2016-10-07 20:57:40 [http-nio-10000-exec-1] ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:129 - Table "WALLETTEST" not found; SQL statement:
update wallettest set orderStatus=? where orderId=? and orderInternalId=? [42102-192]
```

**Console log After setting spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update**

```
2016-10-07 21:20:19 [main] INFO  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:349 - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-10-07 21:20:19 [main] INFO  LogHelper:31 - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: default
        ...]
2016-10-07 21:20:19 [main] INFO  Version:37 - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.11.Final}
2016-10-07 21:20:19 [main] INFO  Environment:213 - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-10-07 21:20:19 [main] INFO  Environment:317 - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-10-07 21:20:19 [main] INFO  Version:66 - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2016-10-07 21:20:20 [main] INFO  HikariDataSource:93 - HikariPool-1 - Started.
2016-10-07 21:20:20 [main] INFO  Dialect:156 - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseDialect
2016-10-07 21:20:21 [main] INFO  SchemaUpdate:105 - HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2016-10-07 21:20:21 [main] INFO  InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl:365 - HHH000262: Table not found: wallettest
2016-10-07 21:20:21 [main] INFO  InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl:365 - HHH000262: Table not found: wallettest
2016-10-07 21:20:21 [main] INFO  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:382 - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-10-07 21:20:21 [main] INFO  QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator:47 - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-10-07 21:20:21 [main] INFO  OrderUpdateEndpoint:25 - Endpoint loaded
2016-10-07 21:20:22 [main] INFO  RequestMappingHandlerAdapter:534 - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@65cefb8b: startup date [Fri Oct 07 21:20:15
 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-10-07 21:20:22 [main] INFO  RequestMappingHandlerMapping:543 - Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.
web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-10-07 21:20:22 [main] INFO  RequestMappingHandlerMapping:543 - Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.
errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-10-07 21:20:22 [main] INFO  SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:354 - Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-10-07 21:20:22 [main] INFO  SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:354 - Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-10-07 21:20:22 [main] INFO  SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:354 - Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-10-07 21:20:23 [main] INFO  AnnotationMBeanExporter:431 - Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-10-07 21:20:23 [main] INFO  AnnotationMBeanExporter:912 - Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2016-10-07 21:20:23 [main] INFO  AnnotationMBeanExporter:667 - Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
2016-10-07 21:20:23 [main] INFO  Http11NioProtocol:179 - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-10000"]
2016-10-07 21:20:23 [main] INFO  Http11NioProtocol:179 - Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-10000]
2016-10-07 21:20:23 [main] INFO  NioSelectorPool:179 - Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2016-10-07 21:20:23 [main] INFO  TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer:185 - Tomcat started on port(s): 10000 (http)
2016-10-07 21:20:23 [main] INFO  Application:57 - Started Application in 8.57 seconds (JVM running for 13.413)
```

**Issue Resolution:**

Spring boot was ignoring the below properties from application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.dataSourceClassName=com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDataSource
spring.datasource.username=dev
spring.datasource.password=developer
spring.datasource.databaseName=MTW
spring.datasource.serverName=localhost
spring.datasource.portNumber=5000
```

Updated the application.properties file as shown below:

```
server.port=10000
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.databasePlatform=org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

# hikariCP

spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sybase:Tds:172.16.12.35:5000/MTW
spring.datasource.connectionTestQuery=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.username=mtw_dev
spring.datasource.password=developer
spring.datasource.poolName=SpringBootHikariCP
spring.datasource.maximumPoolSize=10
spring.datasource.connectionTimeout=60000
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver
```

**Imp point**: Also instead of using jconn4.jar as external jar in eclipse, changed it into maven dependency using below command:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.sybase -DartifactId=sybase-jconnect -Dversion=7.07 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true -Dfile=jconn4.jar
```

This command moves the Sybase jar as dependency in local maven repo

**And then mentioned it in my pom.xml in dependency section.**

Did this because without mentioning the jconn4 as maven dependency rather than just external jar in build path, Spring boot + hikariCP complains that: Cannot load sybase driver class:

```
threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
```

**From which it seems that driver also should be part of pom.xml for Spring boot to select it automatically.**